# Getting values of checked check boxes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello I want values of checked check boxes after click on OK button.
Below is code

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkABC" Content="ABC" Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,0,0,0"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="chkXYZ" Content="XYZ" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,0,0,0"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="chkPQR" Content="PQR" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,0,0,0"/>
```

If user select ABC and PQR, then click on OK button, I want ABC and PQR at backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the elements by name in code behind. E.g chkABC

Suppose if have a button click handler, then u can inspect IsChecked value of checkbox
as follow

```
if(chkABC.IsChecked.HasValue && chkABC.IsChecked.Value)
```

Similarly u can check other checkboxes as well to get checked checkboxes.
For more info on states check out the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Controls_Primitives_ToggleButton_IsChecked)

Answer (score 0):

could you please be more specific on what you meant by **Value**
for this answer i would assume what you wanted was the `Content` property

Depending on how you want your data, you could use LINQ
for demo i would assume that these checkboxes are in some of Grid named `grid`

```
string[] values = grid.Children
    .OfType<CheckBox>()
    .Where(cb => (bool)cb.IsChecked)
    .Select(cb => cb.Content.ToString())
    .ToArray();
```

Something of this sort would work